# Searching multiple sheets for a key word then creating a pivot

Tags: vba, search, pivot, worksheet

I have a code to create the pivot table I need, but I want to add the coding to search each tab for a key word and if found highlight the tab and create the pivot table. Start Search for KeyWord = "XXXXX" in first tab and if found highlight and create pivot below, then continue to next tab, loop until done. If keyword not found do nothing and continue to next tab.

```
Sub Create pivot()
ActiveSheet.Select
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Tab
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
Dim pc As PivotCache

Set shtSrc = ActiveSheet
Set shtDest = shtSrc.Parent.Sheets.Add()
shtDest.Name = shtSrc.Name & "-Pivot"

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=shtSrc.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
pc.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=shtDest.Range("A3"), _
    TableName:="PivotTable1"
With shtDest.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .SaveData = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = False
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .InGridDropZones = False
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = False
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
   ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Suspense?")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("APC LC2 Amount"), "Sum of APC LC2 
Amount", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Partner LC2 Amount"), "Sum of Partner LC2 
Amount", _
    xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField 
ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("LC2 Amount"), _
    "Sum of LC2 amount", xlSum

 End Sub
```

Comment: Correction: Start Search for KeyWord = "XXXXX" in first tab Column "E"and if found highlight and create pivot below, then continue to next tab, loop until done. If keyword not found do nothing and continue to next tab.

Comment: There are over 800 results on Stack Overflow, if you search for ["loop over sheets"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D%5Bvba%5Dloop+over+sheets) including tags [Excel] and [VBA]. I hope, that one of it helps.